# View at the Center in a relativelayout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a `relativelayout` which contains a `progressbar` and a Loading `textview`..i need the `progressbar` and text view to cone at the center of relative layout.But its coming more towards right not at the center.below is my code..

```
<RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="26dp" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:background="@drawable/border">
                        <ProgressBar
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


              <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/TextViewProgress"
                        android:text="Loading"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
                        />
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the container of your RelativeLayout. Isn't the RelativeLayout itself aligned to right in it's container?

Comment: First , change the height of your relativaLayout to 
`match_parent` instead of `26dp` and then add the full xml code of your layout

Comment: @Houcine: Thanks.but i need to have  control of the height of the relative layout.i.e i have a grid view below which im adding this relative layout at the bottom of the screen..

Comment: @peekler: I din get you..what do you mean by  RelativeLayout itself aligned to right

Comment: @user1340801 : add the full xml layout code and we will help you to fix this problem , it's not a big dal trust me , just edit your question and add the full xml layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `android:gravity="center"` to the `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="26dp" 
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
   android:background="@drawable/border"
   android:gravity="center">

   <ProgressBar
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar"
       android:layout_width="20dp"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/TextViewProgress"
       android:text="Loading"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="16dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a LinearLayout inside of it :

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp" 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         android:background="@drawable/border">
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>
                    <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                     />


          <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewProgress"
                    android:text="Loading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    />
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's just an example. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Perfect i checked .

```
<RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:background="@drawable/icon">
                        <ProgressBar
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


              <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/TextViewProgress"
                        android:text="Loading"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/border">
                    <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                     />


          <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewProgress"
                    android:text="Loading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
                    />
```